# Constraining queries based on aggregations of properties of associations

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-entities

Quick question: would this trigger one query per each Tag item?

```
public static IQueryable<Tag> WhereTagHasLivePosts(this IQueryable<Tag> q)
{
    return q.Where(t => t.Posts.Where(p => DateTime.Now >= p.PublishTime && p.IsPublished == true).Count() > 0);
}
```

t.Posts.Where is actually an extension on IEnumerable, rather than IQueryable, so it seems like this might not be a good idea.

Thanks in advance,

Rei

Comment: unrelated to the real question, but you could simplify to t.Posts.Any(p => DateTime.Now >= p.PublishTime && p.IsPublished) - generally it's faster since it can exit the check as soon as it finds a match instead of having to count the matches over the entire source.

Comment: Tip: it's more performant to use **.Any()** in place of **.Count() > 0**

Comment: Ahh, good point. Thanks!

After I posted I noticed that t.Posts.Count(p => ...) would have been a bit more straightforward, but I figured that the resulting query would be the same. Any() would be better for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're exactly right - `t.Posts` is an `EntityCollection` (in Linq-to-SQL, it would be an `EntitySet`) and as such implements `IEnumerable` and not `IQueryable`.

While the thread was about Linq-to-SQL, it's the same logic as this:

http://damieng.com/blog/2009/06/01/linq-to-sql-changes-in-net-40

Mikeon says:

> [...] EntitySet which is NOT IQueryable.
>
> This prevents usage of linq2sql in any real life scenario.
>
> Consider:
>
> client.Orders.Where(o=>o.Total>1000);
>   // runs linq to objects rather than linq to sql
>
> Same problem exists in entiy framework.

Damien responds:

> @Mikeon: EntitySet is the loaded
>   in-memory collection for
>   relationships.
>
> If you want all the orders for a
>   specific client where the total is
>   greater than 100 then you perform:
>
> db.Orders.Where(o => o.Client ==
>   client && o.Total > 1000)